# Why can't I use style with every draw command in tikz, why can I only set it for the whole picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
    \documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,tdplot_main_coords]


    \coordinate (O) at (1,1,1);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1.414213}{54.68636}{45}

    \draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Py)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (Py)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=pink,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Py)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- cycle;

 \tdplotsetmaincoords{10}{10}%%%%%%%%%%%%this is not changing the rotation since the begin tikzpicture has alread used it once

 \coordinate (M) at (3,2,1);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1.414213}{54.68636}{45}

    \draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Py)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (Py)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=pink,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Py)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- cycle;
\end{document}
```

according to http://latex-community.org/tikz-3dplot_example.pdf
instead of

```
      \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,tdplot_main_coords]
```

I can do

```
      \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}

  \draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5,tdplot_main_coords] (O) -- ($(O) + (Py)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;%inlcude the style for every draw separately.
```

Why might this not be working in my case?

I want to do this so that I can change the style per `\draw` command.

---

The problem seems to be with
`\tdplotsetcoord{P}{1.414213}{54.68636}{45}`

Even if I use the `tdplot_main_coords` style `\draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5,tdplot_main_coords]`
the position of P, Px...etc is returned same as to when the style is not used.

How to counter this?

Comment: Please refrain from using `minimal` class. It's not meant to provide a minimal document but a minimal available TeX instruction set (for more technical purposes) which can give completely different results than, say from `article`. You can use `preview` or `standalone` classes or simply use `article`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't exactly know the inner workings but a quick test shows that it has to do something with the transformation matrix of the `tikzpicture`. Hence, scoping the relevant parts gives a result which looks like what you are after.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]

\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \coordinate (O) at (1,1,1);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1.414213}{54.68636}{45}

    \draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Py)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (Py)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Pz)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Px)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=pink,fill opacity=0.5] ($(O) + (Py)$) -- ($(O) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(O) + (P)$) -- ($(O) + (Pyz)$) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{10}{10}
 \coordinate (M) at (3,2,1);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1.414213}{54.68636}{45}

    \draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Py)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (Py)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] (M) -- ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Pz)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Px)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxz)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=pink,fill opacity=0.5] ($(M) + (Py)$) -- ($(M) + (Pxy)$) -- ($(M) + (P)$) -- ($(M) + (Pyz)$) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]